# JQWidgets: Adding an autoWidth method to jqxComboBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

I'm trying to develop a method that calculates the optimal width of a jqxComboBox.
I first wrote a function called widthFit which does the following:

1. Find the item with the longest text in the list of the jqxComboBox
2. Find the width in pixels of that text based on the current theme. This is done by creating a hidden  and getting its width (as shown in the code below)

```js
 function widthFit(data,displayMember)
 {
  var font_size=$(".jqx-widget").css("font-size");
  var font_name=$(".jqx-widget").css("font-name");
  var n=data.length;
  var width=0;
  var lbl='';
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   item= data[i][displayMember];
   if(item.length>width)
   {
    width=item.length;
    lbl=item;
   }
  }
  $("body").append($("<span id='string_span' style='font-name: "+font_name +"; font-size:"+font_size+"'>"+lbl+"</span>"));
  $("#string_span").hide();
  width=$("#string_span").width();
  $("#string_span").remove();
         // +50px to fit the down-arrow button      
         return width+50;
  
 }
```

Then in the bindingComplete event of the jqxComboBox I added a call to resize the widget's width using the function I created as follows:

```js
$("#jqxComboBox").on('bindingComplete', function (event) {
      $("#jqxComboBox").jqxComboBox({width:widthFit(data,"title")});
  });
```

I got what I wanted except that the "head" of the combo isn't correctly re-sized as shown in the picture below:
[image]

Here is a JSFIddle link that shows the whole code.
http://jsfiddle.net/MedYounes/L23x6u4n/

I would be glad if I find help for this point.

Comment: Is `widthFit` function required? Just remove the `widthFit` call from `bindingComplete`

Comment: for sure it is necessary to calculate the optimal length.

Comment: Just have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/L23x6u4n/5/. Hope it helps.